# How to display a fixed line of text in Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

I have seen many command-line apps, especially `apt` doing this thing-- displaying the progress at the bottom which is fixed, while the rest of the text automatically scrolls down:
[image]

How can I achieve this behaviour in my scripts? Is it possible with just bash script or do I need to use some external tools?

Comment: Just use bash with `printf "%s\r" yourvars` the `'\r'` is the *Carriage-Return* and will return to the start of the same line allowing you to overwrite what was there over and over again. You  can use `tput` or ANSI escape sequences to position the cursor anywhere on the screen you like (terminal dependent, but generic VT100 terminals provide a bit of uniformity)

Comment: Wow, that's great. Thanks a lot. By the way, what are **generic VT100 terminals**?

Comment: It is simply a set of terminal capabilities that many software terminals (like xterm, konsole, etc..) emulate in the way their terminal code is written. (int the old days the VT100 was an actual type of computer terminal made by DEC in the late 70's)

Comment: Thanks, but how to put that text to the bottom? I can only bring back the cursor to the same line to overwrite the current content.

Comment: There is a rather extensive discussion on using them here [Build your own Command Line with ANSI escape codes](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html) with the basic definitions here [ANSI Escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) See **Cursor Position:**

Comment: Thanks a lot for these valuable links. I have been searching for a complete documentation on escape sequences.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you want to place the cursor at the bottom position, then use the save cursor position function, print your text and then restore the cursor position to the save location. It's a bit non-intuitive -- but then much of the use of escapes were from the 70's or earlier where you were basically issuing hardware commands to manipulate the screen (terminal or green-phosphorous display).